# Wrapping matrix in R console

Tags: r

I am printing out 50 rows and 12 columns for each of the months.

For some odd reason, it is wrapping around Month 10 and there is another block created with 2 columns to catch Nov and Dec.

Tried expanding window, changed fonts but does not seem to appear properly still. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you type `Salary` in the console after expanding the window? For me it auto-adjusts the width based on window size.

Answer (score 1):

By default text width is set to 80 characters and you can change it  with:

```
options(width=XX)
```